What is the basis of the Overview effect?
What is the basis of the cognitive shift, called "Overview effect", reported by some astronauts while viewing the Earth from space, that is, what is its cause or why does it appear in these circumstances?
This question is important because the first astronaut means to be not simply the one who had the honor of being among the people who flew for the first time on a new unique rocket, but also to be an extremely brave person, and Alan Shapard was such a person, however, on February 5, 1971, Alan Shepard, as a commander of the Apollo 14 mission, takes his first steps on the Moon and became at age 47 the oldest person to walk on the Moon, and later this extremely brave person said about it: "when I first looked back at the Earth, standing on the Moon, I cried" - that's what the Overview Effect is - so strong, that even extremely brave person cried, but if the Overview Effect causes such strong feelings and even crying in the orbit of the Earth and on the Moon, then what will happen during more distant spaceflights - this is why it is extremely necessary before such spaceflights to find the basis of the Overview Effect, that is, what is its cause, why does it appear in these circumstances, and to confirm or disprove the hypothesis that a human, having traveled so far from his home planet, will encounter the Overview Effect of such strength that he will not be able to cope with it without prior preparation!

ok, i've posted this question there too: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/what-is-the-basis-of-the-overview-effect
